# On IOS12, my Phonegap splash screen freezes

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

This used to work great on older versions of IOS, but since IOS12, my app has stopped working.  Basically it shows the splash screen, but doesn't do anything after that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated as this has been difficult.  I use build.phonegap.com to create the IPA.  In config.xml I specify version Phonegap version cli-7.1.0.

I've tried disabling the splash screen with these directives, but no luck:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>
```

I'm not sure what else to try?  Can I just disable the splashscreen plugin altogether?

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"  />
```

But I believe IOS apps require a splash screen?  I wish I could see what if any errors are generated?  Is there a way?

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody curious, I did solve this.

To config.xml, I added:

```
<preference name="WKSuspendInBackground" value="false" />
```

I also disabled the following plugins:

```
<!--preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/-->
<!--preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/-->
<!--plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"  /-->
```

It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I am using framework7 for my app.I have used navigator.splashscreen.hide() to hide the splash screen on IOS12. It works for me.

Example:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function(){ 
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
})
```